# How to prevent JQuery script from repeating in a custom infinite scroll script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the latest JQuery. The problem is if the user scrolls too fast the script fires twice in a row. If the user scrolls at normal speeds or very slowly, the script works normally. I have the js at the bottom of the page. I added a timeout when calling the function, but all it does is wait for the timeout and then repeats the script twice. The repeating doesn't happen all the time. I have the setting to call the function at -10px of the scroll height. Also, any attempt I've made to put a loading gif doesn't seem to work, even with a delay on loading the gif. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

```
<body>
    <div class="contentholderwrap"></div>

    <div id="dataresult"></div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function lastPostFunc(){
            var endid = $(".contentholderwrap:last").attr("id");
            if (endid != "1000000000000") {
                $.post("main.php?lastid="+$(".contentholderwrap:last").attr("id"), function(data) {
                    if (data != ""){
                        $(".contentholderwrap:last").after(data);
                    }
                    $('#dataresult').empty();
                });
            }
        };

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() -10 ){
            setTimeout(lastPostFunc, 500);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your timeout didn't work because all it did was delay the function call, but it still queued one up every time the `.scroll` event happened. If you want to implement a delay you need to use `setTimeout()` to prevent more than one request within a set period of time:

```
var timerid = null;
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if (timerid === null &&
       $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() -10 ){
         lastPostFunc();
         timerid = setTimeout(function() { timerid = null; }, 500);
   }
});
```

Alternatively you could update your `lastPostFunc()` function so that it won't do anything if the previous Ajax request is still in progress:

```
 var ajaxInProgress = false;
 function lastPostFunc(){
     if (ajaxInProgress) return;

     var endid = $(".contentholderwrap:last").attr("id");
     if (endid != "1000000000000") {
         $.post("main.php?lastid="+endid, function(data) {
             if (data != ""){
                $(".contentholderwrap:last").after(data);
             }
             $('#dataresult').empty();
             ajaxInProgress = false;
         });
         ajaxInProgress = true;
     }
 }
```

(A third option is to admit that infinite scroll can be really annoying, so use a "Load more" button/link instead.)

Comment: Well, this stop scrolling altogether. When scrolling down, nothing happens. I used firebug in Firefox to debug, but I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: Did you use the first change (timeout) or the second change (ajax)? And can you put a copy of your updated code somewhere I can see it, e.g., on http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: You had an extra ), at the end of the lastpost function. When scrolling, it's ignoring the timer delay. You used function() in the scroll function which calls the functions immediately. When removing the (), function is never called. So I guess I'm without a delay?

Comment: Sorry, the first code seems to prevent repeating code. The delay option doesn't seem to work at all. Using both options simultaneously, still no delay, but so far, no repeats either.

Comment: Oh, you had === in the scroll function, I changed that to ==. The delay works too. Good stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about the extra `)` - I've edited the answer to remove it. Regarding `===` vs `==`, in this case it really shouldn't matter - I'm surprised it made a difference in your code. Anyway, glad you got it working.